# returning a string from askopenfilename() to a entry box

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have seen many postings on the use of askopenfilename(), however I still can't seem to find anything to help me display the full file path in an entry box once I have selected said file.  below I have included where I have left off.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

global a

def browse():
    a = askopenfilename(title='select new file')

root = Tk()

a = StringVar()

l = Label(root, text="new file: ")
l.pack()

e = Entry(root, width=25, textvariable=a)
e.pack()

b = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browse)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `browse` function the local variable a does indeed contain the full path to your file. THe issue is that you have to call the StringVar's `.set()` method, you can't just assign to the variable you bound to the StringVar. Replace `a = askopenfilename(title='select new file')` with `a.set(askopenfilename(title='select new file'))` and you will see the filename appear in the StringVar in your interface.

Please note that your program is not well-structured for a GUI interface task, but I presume at present your major difficulty is learning to use the primitives.