# Issue displaying selected file path in Entry() box - Python Tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, path, blank-line

This is my first post here, but I cannot find a solution elsewhere.
I'm using Python's Tkinter library to create a minimal Hashcat GUI Hash-Cracker, just for fun :)
It takes in a .hccapx hash file and a .dict dictionary file from sub-directories added to Hashcat-5.1.0 on Windows 10.
My issue is marked here:

```
def browsehccapx():
if path.exists(".\selected.hccapx"):
    os.remove(".\selected.hccapx")
else:
    pass
hccapxpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".\hccapxfiles", title="Select handshake .hccapx file",filetypes=((".hccapx files","*.hccapx"),("all files","*.*")))
hccapxpath = shutil.copy(hccapxpath, rootdir)
os.rename("{}".format(hccapxpath), ".\selected.hccapx")
```

and this is the Entry box that wont display the variable hccapxpath:

```
hccapxpathtxt = Entry(window, textvariable=hccapxpath, width=64, bg="white")
```

Can someone tell me why hccapxpathtxt will not display hccapxpath inside the Entry() box after browsehccapx() is called?
Do I need a different method to allow browsehccapx() to output the selected file path to the Entry() box?
Right now the program works perfectly fine when configured inside Hashcat directory, the only problem remaining is that the .hccapx file and .dict wordlist file are not displayed once selected.
All help is greatly appreciated! So is constructive criticism! Thank you in advance to everyone who takes time to try to help :)
The full python file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/6GQxSxfb

Comment: `hccapxpath` is not a `StringVar` and so the entry will not be updated when `hccapxpath` is changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [returning a string from `askopenfilename()` to a entry box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083298/7414759)

Comment: @acw1668 I am currently trying to find where to define `hccapxpath` as a `StringVar`. `hccapxpath` should be the output of `filedialog.askopenfilename()`, but when i run `hccapxpath =  StringVar(filedialog.askopenfilename(...))` I get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_root'`. I appreciate the assistance, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Thank you @acw1668. I defined `hccapxpath` as a `StringVar()` under global variables, then ran the following updated function to get the `Entry()` box to display the path:

```
def browsehccapx():
if path.exists(".\selected.hccapx"):
    os.remove(".\selected.hccapx")
else:
    pass
fullhccapxpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".\hccapxfiles", title="Select handshake .hccapx file",filetypes=((".hccapx files","*.hccapx"),("all files","*.*")))
fullhccapxpath = shutil.copy(fullhccapxpath, rootdir)
hccapxpath.set(fullhccapxpath)
os.rename("{}".format(fullhccapxpath), ".\selected.hccapx")
```

The pastebin link is good for 6 months.
I hope this helps others with a similar issue in the future!

Comment: You should check whether `fullhccapxpath` is empty because user can close the dialog without selecting file.

Comment: Functioning program available at https://github.com/freedmanry/GUICAT

Comment: What I mean is that the line `fullhccapxpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(...)` will assign `fullhccapxpath` an empty string if no file is selected in the file dialog.

Comment: Understood, i found the same issue. Im thinking an if/else statement that calls `os.path.isfile()` to determine if there was no file selected  and to pass if that is the case. i will update with my solution shortly